# Favicon not showing in Safari 5.1

Tags: favicon, safari

Is there a reason why a *favicon.ico* is not showing in Safari 5.1 on Mac? It shows on every other browser I have tested except the above mentioned one. In Safari on Windows it shows.

I've declared it like this:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico" />`

Comment: Have you fixed it already? The favicon loads fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that Safari on Mac is showing favicons for other websites (try any stackexchange website), you probably need to [clear the browser cache](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030216085845456).

Also, try adding a random number (using JS or Server-script like PHP) to your favicon reference, like below:

**EDIT-** Also, add type attribute and try again? (see below)

```
<!-- FAVICON -->
        <link 
        rel = "shortcut icon" 
        type = "image/x-icon" 
        href = "http://www.dixitsolutions.com/favicon.ico?23189123" />
```

Comment: Clearing the cache was the first thing I did. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding the type attribute, check the edited answer.